# wxPython MainLoop() Crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, wxpython, mainloop

Sometimes when I run the project my MainLoop crashes and I get an exit code. I don't know how to debug the code and see where is the line that crashes it. My project is long and has many classes so I can't copy it to here. How to find this line?

Comment: Run it from the command line. That, at least, will give you the error and line number

Comment: I tried it, The gui crashed and I got no error

Comment: @YuvalSharon email the code to legorooj@protonmail.com and I'll have a read. Some errors just need another set of eyes.

Comment: The project contain more than 2000 lines and complicated to understand. I think that you won't succeed to find this specific problem.

Comment: If I get an exception and a line number I will understand the problem. I just need to find the way to get it.